# Sometimes, when screen sharing in Chrome, the entire window tab is empty

Tags: google-chrome, screensharing

So I have an application that needs to record user screen (specifically the entire screen).

Sometimes, when the uses stops sharing, locks the screen and then unlocks it, the "Entire screen" option is empty. This is fixed on refresh.

So far I have only been able to reproduce this problem under Windows.

[image: Here is how it looks]

And help with why this happens or how to fix it are appreciated.